# What is the best way to import an module if it is not needed in all time?

Tags: python, python-import

what is the best way to import an module if it is not needed in all time?

Should i import the module in the head of the file without a condition or should i import it with a condition?

Will the import slow down the application with the import in the head?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from app.settings import CONDITION
from foo.bar import myClass

if CONDITION:
    # ... do some action with myClass
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from app.settings import CONDITION

if CONDITION:
    from foo.bar import myClass
    # ... do some action with myClass
```

Comment: "*if it is not needed in all time?*": do you mean that `myClass` can be provided by two different modules (if one doesn't exist, you use the other one), or just that `myClass` is used only once?

Comment: Its just used only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), you should place all your import statements at the top of the file, and I agree with this, even if you are only going to use it once in a function.

Your code can be a bit unreadable if your import statements are scattered across your code.

As for if the imports will slow your script down: probably. But not in any great numbers that you should really be worrying about.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Then i will put all imports in the head.

Answer (score 1):

with the import at the head, whatever milliseconds import takes will be during the startup of your program. Its better than making your program stop to import when a certain condition is active.

Also, importing at the top makes for clean code.

Answer (score 1):

Your second way of importing is probably better if you only occasionally need the module. Especially if the module does some heavy initialization works.

What `import` does is calling the builtin function `__import__(name)`, see [details](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

```
if True:
    import os
```

is equivalent to:

```
if True:
    os = __import__('os')
```

And the best part is that the result of `__import__` is cached, so you don't need to worry that by calling it multiple times you would end up parsing the module multiple times.

**EDIT**: The other answers do have good points, that it is cleaner to have it on top and if the condition is ever evaluated to True, you end up paying the price sooner or later.

I guess it depends on your specific use case too. For example, often times we want to choose one of the implementations of a particular module, we do:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Comment: yes the try:except part is another way to import but only if i wanna replace functionality.